# How to recover Yahoo! account

Tags: account-recovery, yahoo-account

I made a Yahoo! account a while ago, and I thought I was just going to use it for small stuff, but I ended up depending on it very heavily. Since I was going to use it only for small stuff, I didn’t really pay attention to the sign up information, so I put a random phone number, and I also did not put a recovery email. I’ve forgotten my password and I can’t get back in. I am depending on this email very heavily so if you have any solutions, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

[Use the Sign-in Helper to get back into your account](https://login.yahoo.com/account/challenge/username?authMechanism=secondary&done=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.com%2F&sessionIndex=QQ--) using your Yahoo ID, mobile number, recovery phone number, or recovery email address. If you forgot your password, be sure to change your password to a strong one that you'll remember after you're in.

**If you don't have recovery option(s), probably you will not be able to sign-in your account.**

From [Yahoo! Help](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/account/fix-problems-signing-yahoo-account-sln2051.html?impressions=true):

> **If account recovery information is incorrect:**
>   We take your privacy and security very seriously, and only let you reclaim an account if you prove you're the rightful owner. When you register for an account, it's up to you to provide valid recovery info that proves ownership. The best way to safeguard your account access is to update your recovery info whenever your mobile phone number or email address changes.
>
> **Sign-in Helper can't recover your account online:**
>   We need valid security and recovery info to protect your account. If you weren't successful with Yahoo Sign-in Helper or the other options above, you likely won't be able to recover your account. If you remember your sign-in information later, you can come back and try again.